# replace javascript não diferenciar maiúsculo ou minúsculo

Tags: javascript

Qual alternativa posso usar para não diferenciar maiúsculo ou minúsculo?

```
location.replace('O=OrderDesc&', '')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Utilize Regex para resolver seu problema:

```
var textoAlterado = locationHref.replace(/O=OrderDesc&/ig, '');
```

A sintaxe para a expressão regular é `/padrão/flags`, sendo que as flags são nossos parâmetros:

`i`: *ignorar maiúsc./minúsc.*

`g`: *corresponder globalmente*

Mais referências sobre *Regex*: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Comment: Isso mesmo, tinha feito uma busca no google mas não lembrava a função, thanks!

Comment: Se a resposta te ajudou e pode ajudar outras pessoas, poderia marca-la como resposta aceita por favor? Obrigado :)

Comment: Só mais uma duvida isso aqui esta correto? locationHref.replace(/OrderDesc/ig, '').replace(/OrderAsc/ig, '');

Comment: Seria assim: `locationHref.replace(/orderbytopsaledesc/ig, '').replace(/orderbytopsaleasc/ig, '');`

Comment: Isso mesmo, tinha ate editado ali antes, estava com o ";" mas de resto tudo certo então, thanks!